# I'm having difficulties with Reactjs (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I'm working on creating a design system in ReactJS using TypeScript, and I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to correctly pass and return types for my components. Here's what I've done so far:

- Moved Components: I've reorganized my components within the design
  system.
- Type Prop Calls: I've updated the way I call and handle types
  in my components.

However, I'm still facing difficulties in making it work as expected. Specifically, I want my component to return one of the defined components, but I seem to be unable to pass the types correctly.

Here's a completed version of my code:

```
import React from "react";
import './title.css'

export type TitleProps = {
  linguage: 'pt-BR' | 'es-CL' | 'en-US'
}


export const Title = ({ linguage }: TitleProps) => {
  return (
    <h1 className="storybook-title-portugues" >
      Gerenciamos sua TI com excelência
    </h1>
  );
}

const getTitlePt = () => {
  return (
    <h1 className="storybook-title-portugues" {...{ linguage: 'pt-BR' }}>
      Gerenciamos sua TI com excelência
    </h1>
  );
}
const getTitleEn = () => {
  return (
    <h1 className="storybook-title--english"{...{ linguage: 'pt-BR' }}>
      We manage your IT with excellence
    </h1>
  );
}
const getTitleEs = () => {
  return (
    <h1 className="storybook-title--espanol"{...{ linguage: '' }}>
      Gestionamos tu TI con excelencia
    </h1>
  );
}
const getTilte = () => {
  if (linguage === 'pt-BR') {
    return getTitlePt
  } else if (linguage === 'en-US') {
    return getTitleEn
  } else {
    return getTitleEs
  }
  return getTilte
}
```

I tried going through PROPS and THIS but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix the typo first of all: getTilte should be getTitle

Another problem is that you're trying to access linguage (it may be a typo ?), but it's not available because you didn't pass it as a parameter or from a higher scope. As you will see that linguage is only reachable by Title functional component and getTitle is out of this functional component.

Your props spreading approach is a bit unusual. It would be cleaner to just directly set them on the component.

Let me refactor your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './title.css';

export type TitleProps = {
  linguage: 'pt-BR' | 'es-CL' | 'en-US';
};

export const Title: React.FC<TitleProps> = ({ linguage }) => {
  const getTitle = () => {
    if (linguage === 'pt-BR') {
      return 'Gerenciamos sua TI com excelência';
    } else if (linguage === 'en-US') {
      return 'We manage your IT with excellence';
    } else {
      return 'Gestionamos tu TI con excelencia';
    }
  };

  const className = () => {
    if (linguage === 'pt-BR') {
      return 'storybook-title-portugues';
    } else if (linguage === 'en-US') {
      return 'storybook-title--english';
    } else {
      return 'storybook-title--espanol';
    }
  };

  return <h1 className={className()}>{getTitle()}</h1>;
};
```

That will fix your problem but I strongly advice you to use a package like i18next or similar libraries to deal with internationalization (i18n) in your projects. Here you can find a i18n sample on codesandbox (not mine): https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-v9cq3

Comment: It worked as expected, thank you very much, it's my first time writing here on stackoverflow. I will study more about componentization in reactjs. I just have a doubt as to what exactly this is for:
React.FC<TitleProps>

Comment: You're welcome. React.FC<TitleProps> is just another way of telling the Prop types to the component. You may use your own method: ({ linguage }: TitleProps). It should also work.